# What is the meaning of the surname Hooch?

Tags: harry-potter, names

What is the meaning of the surname Hooch (Madam Hooch from the *Harry Potter* books)? Has J. K. Rowling said what it means, in-universe?

In the Russian translation she is called like Madam Hooch or Madam Tryuck (it means *trick*). I found the translation of the word hooch - marijuana or alcoholic drink, also the word hoochie. And I think that her haircut in the movie completely corresponds to this translation.

Comment: There are some really frightening definitions out there.  You'd never see Madam Hooch the same way after seeing those ;)

Comment: She is also called Hooch in the german version. In German the word "Hoch" means tall or as an adjectiv high.

Comment: @nestario Since that is the answer, would you mind turning it into one, so OP could accept it (probably with a remark that it was most likely chosen, because she is flying *high* all the time :P Not the inebriated kind of *high* of course, but the actual above ground kind)

Comment: +1 because it’s a good question (not sure why it’s gotten so many downvotes, but I guess it must be because of the original wording with “what do you think about…”). I don’t understand what you think her haircut in the movie has to do with marijuana or booze, though… her haircut seems perfectly normal to me..?

Comment: Her haircut in film was pretty standard for the actress, fwiw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual meaning of "hooch" in English is booze, although it is particularly likely to mean smuggled or otherwise untaxed liquor (e.g. moonshine).  Its meaning is sometimes generalized to other intoxicants, such as marijuana, but the alcoholic meaning is the primary one.

"De Hooch" is also a Dutch surname, most associated with a family of painters from the Dutch golden age.  The Dutch word is a cognate to German "hoch," meaning high (and both "hoch" and "hooch" are somewhat more distantly cognate to "high" itself).  Presumably, this was the association that Rowling was going for by naming the flying instructor Madame Hooch.  The Oxford English Dictionary says the alcoholic meaning is originally and chiefly North American, so she may not have realized the other associations the name might bring.

Comment: Hooch is specifically a sour fermented liquid, produced in preparing sourdough, its key characteristic is that it is sour. It is also an alcoholic beverage made from citrus juice similarly to how hard apple cider is made from the juice of crushed apples. Likewise, it is sour.

Comment: @Escoce:  I added something from the usage notes of the Oxford English Dictionary.  However, the OED does not mention the specific meaning you mention, nor have I ever heard it before.  Googling turned up "Hooper's Hooch," a British product produced from 1995-2003 and 2012-present, which may be referred to as just "hooch" because of most Britons' unfamiliarity with the word.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooch

Comment: In English "hooch" also means "a shelter or improvised dwelling." (This is actually a word I use every year in an annual art community I participate in, 'cause one of our venues has several :).

Comment: Most Brits in my part of the country would only know 'hooch' as the alcoholic drink!

Comment: @Lexible I think using the word "hooch" as a dwelling is a corruption of the word "hutch". I know that during Vietnam, it was common to refer to a small building as a "hooch", but still, I think it was most likely a mispronunciation of "hutch".

Comment: Probably worth noting that the surname "Hooch" as in the painter De Hooch is also pronounced differently from the drink - "Ho-okh."

Answer (score 1):

"Hooch" may derive from "Hoochinoo", the name of a tribe of Native Americans that made a distilled liquor. See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoochinoo